# Trouble understanding boost copy_file "File exists" error message

Tags: c++, boost

I am investigating an issue in my program where the following error message appears:

```
boost::fs: boost::filesystem::copy_file: File exists: "path/to/file1", "path/to/file2" path1="path/to/file1" path2="path/to/file2"
```

I guess the issue is that some file already exists and that overwriting it is impossible, but I am not sure which file exactly.

Is it `file1` that can't be copied to `path/to/file2` or the opposite? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

The boost documentation [Here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) says the following:

```
void         copy_file(const path& from, const path& to);
void         copy_file(const path& from, const path& to,
                   system::error_code& ec);
void         copy_file(const path& from, const path& to,
                   copy_option option);
void         copy_file(const path& from, const path& to,
                   copy_option option, system::error_code& ec);
```

Also, you can check if a file exists using:

```
if ( !boost::filesystem::exists( "myfile.txt" ) )
{
  std::cout << "Can't find my file!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that such checks are inherently racy: If a different process creates the file after your check has ran, but before the copy operation completes, you still run into the error. So your code still needs to account for that situation, even though you checked it before.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I didn't even consider multithreading in this one.